# Energy or power signal for continuous signal

Tags: power-spectral-density, continuous-signals, signal-power, integration, signal-energy

I have solved $w(t) = 1dt$ and determined it as power but when $w(t) =\Pi\left(\frac{t}{T_0}\right)$ it is energy.

Comment: Any explanation :?

Comment: Could you add more detail as to what your question is and why?